# Ubuntu 14.04 and higher not running properly on my computers

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I am confronted with a very strange problem.

After having used Ubuntu 12.04 for years on my 3+ computers without any major problems, I am now trying to upgrade to 14.04 (or later). But on none of my computers this gives satisfactory results.

A few details: one is a Samsung laptop with an nVidia graphics chip and i3 processor.

With 12.04 I could happily use one of the nVidia closed source drivers and it worked like a charm. With 14.04 I cannot do that. When I tried it the whole system became useless and I had to reinstall Ubuntu. With Nouveau it works reasonable but every now and then 'internal errors' occur.

Another computer is an Acer desktop with nVidia graphics as well.

Here about the same problem but the crashes became so frequent that I replaced the standard Ubuntu with Unity by Ubuntu Mate which works sort of reasonable now.

The third computer that ran 12.04 well is an older Averatec laptop with a Sis graphical chip. This one is a real pain: I tried just about every distro > 12.04 but nothing is really useful.

What I am beginning to fear is that Ubuntu is no longer the OS of choice for older computers. Or hopefully I am wrong...